# 16.04.1 LTS error while apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates

I get error while updating:

```
al@alpc:~/android$ sudo apt-get update
...
Err:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
...
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

Googling gives me that this error happens while using old Ubuntu releases, but I use newly downloaded 16.04.1:

```
al@alpc:~/android$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I try to do that because I can't install `mingw32`:

```
al@alpc:~/android$ sudo apt-get install mingw32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mingw32
```

Here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe multiverse
```

How to fix that? How to get successful result of `apt-get update` command and installed mingw32 using official repos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete these two lines (they're at the bottom of the sources list):

```
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy universe multiverse
 # deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe multiverse
```

Run `sudo apt-get update` and you shouldn't have any errors.

I'm honestly not sure how you managed to get a repository for 13.10 on a newly installed 16.04 machine, but that'll get rid of it.

However your main concern is that `mingw32` can't be installed on Xenial 64bit. Its alternative for 64 bit `mingw-w64` can be installed installed instead. Both provide the same libraries targeting Windows. Run the following command to install:

```
sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
```

Comment: OP obviously ran `add-apt-repository` with `saucy multiverse` that they found somewhere in the net.

Comment: @Pilot6 that's very likely, but I wonder why they left that out completely, and actually implied the opposite.

Comment: They do not remember the commands they run. My dad also does weird things on Ubuntu that I can't guess how he does. But he always says that he did not do anything. ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 Well that makes sense. Let's see if this works for them, or if there's another problem they forgot about :p.

Comment: You haven't completed your answer

Comment: @Anwar what'd I miss?

Comment: Hint: They wanted to install something :).You like me adding an answer?

Comment: @Anwar fine, but their question is about this.

Comment: @Anwar whoops. lemme fix that

Comment: Edited a bit. :)